# Attach javascript/jquery event on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamic, traversal, mutation-observers

I've seen a lot of different questions similar to this, but all of them generally targeted a specific selector. Please let me know if there is a duplicate somewhere and I've missed it.

Take this scenario:

You want to build a jquery plugin for a wordpress, drupal, or basically any site that uses third party functionality. Since you don't know ahead of time every specific event and selector you will need to target how would you add jquery/javascript functionality to elements that are created dynamically. Plus you don't know how the element is created (callback using ajax/php/etc).

Example:

I recently tried adding select2 or selectize to my entire site. Unfortunately, since I can't determine ahead of time when select elements (from other plugins/modules) will be added, I can't ensure that the select jquery will work on newly created selects.

**Select2**

This is the normal way but doesn't work on dynamically created or cloned selects:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("select").select2();
    });
</script>
```

If I knew all the events that added these selects I could simply do the following:

```
 $( ".some_button_that_creates_new_selects" ).on( "click", function() {
        jQuery("select").select2(); 
    });
 });
```

However, since I don't know all the selectors of dynamic selects ahead of time (since many are added by 3rd party plugins), select2 will not work on new selects. So the above would only work on a per case senerio.

I need to find a way to traverse through the dom tree and recognize when new selects are created.

I tried targeting several events with .on but it didn't work well at all.

I read that the javascript `document.getElementsByTagName` recognizes changes in the dom and are reflected in the collection. I also looked into `querySelectorAll`, but not sure exactly how it works.

I also tried messing with the `MutationObserver` and checking if the `.addednodes.length` of select tags changed, but I didn't really get anywhere.

**UPDATE**

After doing some testing I realized that the problem might lie within the select2 plugin itself. Select2 loads dynamic selects but doesnt get the positioning. Chrome eventually throws typeerros : cannot read property 'find' of null, cannot read property 'hasclass' of null.

[image: Example adding the select2 plugin to wordpress. Clicking quick edit adds new fields]

[image: New selects don't load properly. and there is no dropdown when clicking on them.]

[image: Clicking once on the select and then below it will load the select2 overlay wrong]

Answer (score 6):

### Solution:

I am going to answer your base question "Attach javscript/jquery event on dynamically created elements".

For adding event on dynamically created elements you have to take advantage or Event Delegation, when a event trigger on an element it propagates.

So if you attach event handler on a root element( it can be body or any parent element which is present when you are attaching this event)

```
$("body").on("click","elementSelector", function(){

});
```

Now this will capture event from dynamically created elements as well.

Comment: Should have mentioned I tried that. It doesn't work though. I think in my current situation, it might be a problem with the particular plugin select2.

Comment: The dynamic created selects look like select2 selects but when you click on them they're frozen. After analyzing generated source in chrome, I noticed that the dropdowns are in fact being added however their positioning is wrong. Select2 appears to add the jquery select dropdown when you actually click on each select and then overlays that dropdown on top of the normal select dynamically with absolute positioning and the top & left& css attributes. When the dynamic selects are created their positioning is not being recognized.

Comment: If you look at the select2 drop in the generated source style generated source is  `style="display: block; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: auto;`  where normally it would look something like this `style="display: block; left: 453.2528381347656px; width: 149px; top: 150.23011016845703px; bottom: auto;` However if you click where the dropdown "should" be it tries to find it's positioning but it gets it wrong and loads it to the right.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to create a function in javascript which will be called everytime when you add any control dynamically on the page and in that function you can placed the check so event will be registered only on new components. e.g.

```
function registerEvents()
{
    //Get all the select events from the page and register events only on those controls which are new ..
    $("select").each(function() {

        if (!$(this).hasClass("registeredEvent")) {

              $(this).addClass("registeredEvent");
              $(this).select2();
        }
    });

}
```

Same results can be achieved through different approaches..

Also check .live event in jquery .. it register events automatically when the new element is added with the same tag or class..

Comment: live method is deprecated few release back, it should not be used.

Comment: yes you are correct.. that's why I suggested custom function to handle these types of situation.

Comment: If you know when the new elements are added like third party provides some callbacks then you initialize select2 plugin on newly created select elements through a function like razahassank mentioned above.

Comment: As far as deprecated .live goes, wasn't it just replaced with .on like how I used it in my example?

Comment: I like this example, however it doesn't seem to be adding registeredEvent to any of the selects... Maybe, I'm missing something... Also, see my update uptop for my particular situation. I think this case might have to do with a problem with select2.

Comment: can you please share the URL so we can easily debug ?