# Cannot initialize select2 on dynamically added element: TypeError: select2 is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've searched for this topic and found some answers like 
[Initialising select2 created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972399/initialising-select2-created-dynamically) and [Attach javascript/jquery event on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095111/attach-javascript-jquery-event-on-dynamically-created-elements). However, my problem cannot be solved for some reason.

Basically, what I want to do is to create another select2 box dynamically when user selected a result in a existing select2 box. What I did is like this:

In the first select2 box, I use

```
.on("select2:select", function (e) {
    prepareDepartment(e.params.data.id);
});
```

to call a function. In this function, I use `$.ajax` to get necessary data. Then in `success` option I create some HTML like this

```
$(".institution-selection").append('<select id="institution" class="form-control search-institution" name="institution">' +
    '<option></option>' +
'</select>');
```

After this, I want to initialize select2 on newly added class `search-institution`:

```
$(".search-institution").select2();
```

However, I got this error

> TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
>   $(".search-institution").select2();

Is there anything I'm missing here?

UPDATE: I have tried to initialize existing element in HTML in `$.ajax` `success` option, still the same error. There is no error if I initialize elements outside `$.ajax` method.

Comment: This is usually a sign that you're loading in multiple versions of jQuery, and Select2 is being overwritten by the second one which is loaded later.

Comment: You are right, the template I'm using loaded another jQuery at footer, remove that fixed the problem.